# Emphasize searching for existing answers in the Site Tour

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I recently used the community support forum for [Mint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mint.com) and really liked their three-second introduction:

[image: mint]

The *very first* instruction presented to new users was to make an attempt to search for an existing question.

When we compare that to the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), there's much less emphasis on utilizing the existing questionbank. Here's the first thing a user sees:

[image: SO Tour]

Throughout the tour there is little (*to no*) mention of Stack Overflow's search functionality. You even get badges and points for asking new questions, but nothing for just solving the answer on your own by looking for existing questions.

It would be nice to add a reminder in the beginning of the tour about trying to search first before asking a question of your own.

Chrome Issues Takes This One Step Further:

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Find answers, ask questions, no distractions?

Comment: In fact, on the SO tour, there's even a big button labelled `Ask a question`. Maybe add a big button labelled `Search questions`?

Comment: While I agree that everyone should do some digging for an answer before asking a question, I would like to point out that I almost never use SO's search to find an answer to a problem. Google generally returns more relevant results much more quickly (and includes other sites).

Comment: @jpmc26, I usually let Google bring me here as well. Although, IMHO SO's own search function is actually pretty good.  In any case, it's not particularly important *where* the searching occurs, just *that* it occurs. The tour page isn't there so much for regular users, but brand new users that have not yet used the site. And they're probably the worst offenders (dupe wise). The community definitely has an expectation that users search before posting, the tour seems like a good place to introduce them to that expectation.

Comment: @matsjoyce: ... and hide the `Ask a question` button until the `Search questions` button has been clicked!

Comment: Some bug ticket systems take the subject line of a new ticket as a search query and forces you to pick an existing ticket and only if it does not exist you are welcome to post a new ticket. Same could be done with questions here.

Comment: @NobuGames, whenever someone is typing a new question in, they [see a list of possible matches](http://i.imgur.com/ADOS27N.png) which can help cut back on duplicates.  I think it's a very good feature, but it can be addressed earlier as well.

Comment: I think when trying to ask a question, you shoud get an infini-scroll results page where the "ask question" button is on the bottom >:)

Comment: Stack Overflow should also consider rewarding those who find good duplicates. I think it would help teach users to search by example, and incentivize duplicate finding for those who provide answers.

Comment: What's worse imo is that the search inside SO is __nowhere__ near as good as a) Google or (!!) b) the results in the sidebar __after__ you have posted the question. (Or, I must admit the suggestions, that come up during typing, but that's a little late!)

Comment: Yes that would be great -> Search before asking.

But SE needs **new** users asking duplicate, debug-my-code-for-me,  why isn't MY code working... and other LOL-type questions or it's going to DIE. Sad but true but it is what it is.. SO can't be perfect - it needs the noise.